# Minimize the product of distances from n fixed points

Tags: reference-request, optimization, cg.comp-geom

Given $n$ *fixed* points $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^n$ in $D$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^D$, consider the following optimization problem:

$$
\begin{align}
  \text{mininize} \ \ \ &\prod_{i=1}^n \lVert p-p_i\rVert\\
  \text{subject to: } & \lVert p-p_i\rVert \ge 1, \text{for } i=1,\cdots,n
\end{align}
$$

The constraint is to make sure that trivial solution $p=p_i$ won't occur.

**Q.** Has there been any literature discussing such problem already?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using Lagrange multipliers? It seems that it should work if $D$ is constant and the points are in general position.

Comment: Yes, $D$ is fixed. And mathematically speaking it does solve the problem. But when $D$ is large, finding all stationary points in the auxiliary function of Lagrange multipliers involves  solving $D$ homogeneous polynomials in $(D+1)$ variables, of degrees $(2n-1)$, which is a hard question itself.